# DHCP Option 26 (MTU) queries

Tags: dhcp, mtu

I could not find much information on option 26 ( MTU ) from the https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2132.txt, I learned the bellow 2 points from the blog http://www.microhowto.info/howto/change_the_mtu_of_a_network_interface_using_dhcp.html

1. Since the MTU of all interfaces in a given subnet should normally be the same, it is best to set this option on a per-subnet basis where possible.
2. In all cases, the setting will not take effect on a client until its DHCP lease is renewed. You can force this by taking the interface down then bringing it back up again:

Is the point 1 standardized or it's a common implementation ?
Does the design should be w.r.t  Subnet instead of interface ?
Does the design should be like, any changes w.r.t subnet, DHCP Server should check whether the particular option ( 26, as Admin can configure at any point of time) been configured ?

From the point-2 w.r.t client, is there any other event from client that can trigger the MTU changes like DHCP-Inform ?

Answer (score 2):

1. The *configuration* in the DHCP server is by subnet (by developer
   choice, but also the easiest thing to do unambiguously), but the MTU
   option applies to the *interface* the client receives it on. 
   Obviously there are cases where there might be contention here, so
   what the client does if it receives competing information on the
   same interface is left to the end host to resolve (if they are on
   different VLANs, then the MTU can often be set per-VLAN, but there
   are other more complex corner cases).
2. There is a `FORCERENEW` message that your DHCP server can issue to
   clients:

   https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3203.txt

   Your clients have to support this mechanism, of course.